# Is there an API for POP/IMAP in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, imap, pop3

In my app I need to access mail programmatically without using a `MFMailComposeViewController`. I have sent email with the help of `SKPSMTPMessage` from google code. Now I have to connect and check mail via POP3 or IMAP. Is there an API to download mail using POP3 or IMAP? I am not looking for a way to interface with Mail.app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot access the mail database in Mail.app, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: In my app having user's mail id and password .and i need to show inbox of that particular account without configure in mail.app

Comment: There is no Apple-provided implementation of POP/IMAP/SMTP. If you need any of this you will need to resort to third-party code or writiNg it yourself.

Comment: thank u for info.i have found SKPSMTPMessage api for sending mail like wise any api for reading inbox and delete inbox mail after read

Comment: @josh thanks to edit and make my question much more clear

Comment: @asta no problem, I'm happy to help! It's the least I can do when I don't know the answer :-)

Comment: any idea about libetpan c library .i found that that s useful for mail client writing .how to start my work with libetpan ?? any tutorial

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try [MailCore](http://www.libmailcore.com). MailCore supports SMTP and IMAP

Answer (score 2):

I tried MailCore and reMail a year ago and it was too complex for me. I don't know if they improved now, but at that time I just gave up on them and written my own code. I uploaded it to sourceforge now, so whoever finds this discussion in google is welcome to try it.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/imap4ios/

Comment: imap4ios will support POP?

Comment: @gnawer, any plan to support POP3?

Comment: Sorry guys, no plans to extend the functionality right now. Currently it's as it says - IMAP only.

Comment: Is there a way to compose a mail using imap4ios

Comment: @Vishnu IMAP is for getting emails only. Sending emails could be POP or SMTP.